# Timout with wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, process, timeout

I have a serious timeout issue with a wcf service.
I will explain the situation:
I have a asp.net that calls wcf service,
The wcf service creates a new thread,
The new thread creates a process that runs a python script.

Note: The website does not wait for the python script to end, it only gets a confirmation the script is running:-).

The python script is created by creating a new process and calling Waitforexit().
The script is a very long script that takes about 5 hours, after about 2 hours the WaitForExit method throws a exception saying "Thread was being aborted".

I am battling for more than a week with this and I am really clueless.
I will be really happy getting some help, I am m sorry in advance if this post is not formatted nicely, it was written by mobile.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possibly the WCF application has been unloaded?  This is why it is always a bad idea to use asp.net as a platform for long-running tasks.  Can you instead create a windows service to run the python script that reads from a message queue posted by the wcf service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having a similar problem.  The web service application stops after a period of inactivity, so the thread will abort.

One way to get around it is to have a Windows service call the web service every 10 seconds or so, or better, have the Windows service pick up the "Job" using a database queue or other similar technique.